# Why Listview Itemtemplate is faster than ViewBase?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, listview

I have a WPF ListView and two scenarios to bind data as following:

1. Setting 'ItemTemplate'

   ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyCustomDataTemplate}"
2. Setting 'ViewBase'

   ListView.View = MyCustomView

And 'MyCustomView' is looks like the following:

```
<local:TileView x:Key="MyCustomView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyCustomDataTemplate}"  CornerRadius="4" SelectionBrush="#FFF18C00" />
```

I uses 'ViewBase' because I nee some extra data like selection brush and others, and also 'TileView' is inherited from 'ViewBase' class.

the question now is why scenario no. 1 is very very fast than scenario no.2? this means for 4000 items the first scenario takes 4 seconds to load all of the items while the second scenario takes about one minute.

I need to use the second scenario for sake of its additional features.

Any help to make it faster?

---

for more information about 'TileView':

```
Public Class TileView
Inherits ViewBase
Private _itemTemplate As DataTemplate
Private _SelectionBrush As Brush = Brushes.Transparent
Private _CornerRadius As New CornerRadius(0)

Public Shared ReadOnly SelectionBrushProerty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionBrush", GetType(Brush), GetType(TileView))
   Public Shared ReadOnly ItemContainerStyleProperty As DependencyProperty = ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleProperty.AddOwner(GetType(TileView))
Public Property ItemContainerStyle() As Style
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty), Style)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Style)
        SetValue(ItemContainerStyleProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ItemTemplate() As DataTemplate
    Get
        Return _itemTemplate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataTemplate)
        _itemTemplate = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property SelectionBrush() As Brush
    Get
        Return MyBase.GetValue(SelectionBrushProerty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Brush)
        MyBase.SetValue(SelectionBrushProerty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultStyleKey() As Object
    Get
        Return New ComponentResourceKey([GetType](), "TileView")
    End Get
End Property
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ItemContainerDefaultStyleKey() As Object
    Get
        Return New ComponentResourceKey([GetType](), "TileViewItem")
    End Get
End Property
  Public Property CornerRadius As CornerRadius
    Get
        Return _CornerRadius
    End Get
    Set(value As CornerRadius)
        _CornerRadius = value
    End Set
End Property
```

EndClass

And no need to illustrate the structure of 'MyCustomDataTemplate' because it is the same in the two scenarios.

Thanks for you all.

Comment: That's probably because your TileView does not support [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls).

Comment: I uses virtualization in the listview template. but how to use it in TileView?